# Dell XPS 15 - Screen Issue

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, graphics

I've recently installed **Ubuntu 18.04** on my laptop, but lately I've got some issue on the screen, but I don't whether is the GPU or the screen itself:
a portion of the screen is flickering and I see on background the window of application that I previously closed.

My laptop is a **Dell XPS 15 9550**:

- CPU: Intel Core i7-6700HQ
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M
- 2GB GDDR5

but when I check the setting for the GPU used, it is returned as an **Intel® HD Graphics 530 (Skylake GT2)**.

Is there a way to know if this problem is related to the screen or to the GPU?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Ubuntu 18.04 system uses the *internal GPU* of your [Intel® Core™ i7-6700HQ Processor (See Processor Graphics))](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/88967/intel-core-i7-6700hq-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-50-ghz.html) and **not** your external (and probably better) NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M GPU.

If your Laptop has a separate GPU, I guess that it's been configured by the manufacturer to use this one instead of the internal one. Hence the flickering.

I do not have a setup like this, so I cannot guide you to the exact menu points to change that. But look for something like 'Graphics settings' in 'System settings' or 'NVidia-Settings' to change your default graphics to the NVidia GPU.

Comment: I followed your advice, but unfortunately it didn't sort the problem out.
I'm afraid that the screen is broken.
Thank you very much for your help anyway